# Is it possible to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sinh x-x\cosh x+\frac{x^3}3}{x^2\tan^3x}$ applying L'Hopital's Rule?

Tags: calculus, limits

I evaluated following limit with taylor series but for a practice I am trying to evaluate it using L'Hopital's Rule:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sinh x-x\cosh x+\frac{x^3}3}{x^2\tan^3x}=\lim_{x\to0}\cfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
$f(x)=\sinh x-x\cosh x+\frac{x^3}3  ,f(0)=0$

$f'(x)=-x\sinh x+x^2, f'(0)=0$

$f''(x)=-\sinh x-x\cosh x+2x, f''(0)=0$

$f'''(x)=-2\cosh x-x\sinh x+2, f'''(0)=0$

It seems it is going to be $0$ for further derivatives.

Also for $g(x)=x^2\tan^3x$, wolfram alpha gives this result:

[image]

Which seems we have $g^{(n)}(x)=0$ too.

So Is there any way to evaluate the limit applying L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: It is a funny thing to read "I used Taylor but failed with L'hospital" because they are in fact the same method. Taylor makes you compute the successive derivatives and evaluate them at $x=0$. So does L'Hospital, identically !

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, but calculations are different. with L'hopital rule we just take derivative several times but in taylor series we place formulas for all functions.

Comment: I usually try to evaluate limits with Hopital rule too. in order to increase my speed at taking derivatives and  doing algebra

Comment: The computations seem different, but they are not.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes. good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the evaluation we can use that

$$\frac{\sinh x-x\cosh x+\frac{x^3}3}{x^2\tan^3x}=\frac{x^3}{\tan^3x}\frac{\sinh x-x\cosh x+\frac{x^3}3}{x^5}$$

and since $\frac{x^3}{\tan^3x} \to 1$ we reduce to evaluate by l'Hospital

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sinh x-x\cosh x+\frac{x^3}3}{x^5}$$

Comment: It really simplify the calculations but It seems the derivatives of numerator is going to be zero as I evaluated until $f'''(x)$

Comment: @soheil I think you need a step more to finish.

Comment: Yes. I got it. $f^{(5)}(0)=-4$ :)

Comment: @soheil That's fine! Well done. This is really an interesting case for a limit which becomes really worst applying blindly l'Hospital rule but with this simplification it becomes solveable by l'HR. This is another reason why standard limits are so important to be recognized.

Comment: @soheil Check your result again, I've obtained $-1/30$.

Comment: I got numerator $-4$ and denominator is $5!$ so it is $-\frac1{30}$

Comment: @soheil Ah ok! that's fine indeed. Bye

Comment: @soheil Note also that this kind of evaluation for the two parts is allowed in this case because we have  a product but it is not allowed in general. Pay attention on that also.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The denominator is of the fifth degree (after linearizing the tangent), so if there is a finite answer you will need five successive applications of L'Hospital.

The numerator is easy:

$$\sinh x-x\cosh x+\frac{x^3}3,$$

$$-x\sinh x+x^2,$$

$$-\sinh x-x\cosh x+2x,$$

$$-2\cosh x-x\sinh x+2$$

$$-3\sinh x-x\cosh x,$$
$$-4\cosh x-x\sinh x.$$

Every time, you need to check that the expression tends to zero (otherwise the limit will not exist because of the zero denominator).

For the denominator, it is really worth to rewrite

$$x^2\tan^3x=x^5\frac{\tan^3x}{x^3}$$ and take the fraction away. Then the fifth derivative is $5!$ and the requested ratio

$$-\frac1{30}.$$

---

For info, keeping the denominator as is, we get

$$2520x^2(\tan(x))^8+6600x^2(\tan(x))^6+3600x(\tan(x))^7+36x^2(\sec(x))^2(\tan(x))^2+\\
5772x^2(\tan(x))^4+8160x(\tan(x))^5+1200(\tan(x))^6+120x\tan(x)(\sec(x))^2+
\\120x^2(\sec(x))^2+1692x^2(\tan(x))^2+5640x(\tan(x))^3+2280(\tan(x))^4+
\\1080x\tan(x)+120(\sec(x))^2+1080(\tan(x))^2$$

and the only nonzero term is $120\sec^2x$.

Comment: Nice the expansion for the last part, even if by hands I'm not sure one can avoid mistakes!